# Was a baseship ever called a basestar in the 1978 Battlestar Galactica?

Tags: battlestar-galactica, battlestar-galactica-1978

In the 1978 *Battlestar Galactica* series the main Cylon ship was always called a baseship. In what episode was it ever called a basestar in 1978? The basestar name was used in the 2004 series only that I can recall.

Comment: I always knew them as basestars even before the reboot series aired.

Answer (score 5):

I don't have the originals to hand, but the transcripts [here](https://byyourcommand.net/transcripts/BYC-Transcript-Home.html) suggest that base star was used in multiple episodes. Early examples:

**Saga of a Star World:**

> IMPERIOUS LEADER I will send with you a base star, entirely under your command.  Lucifer?

**Lost Planet of the Gods:**

> BALTAR As they did at Carillon?  Hmm?  Hm.  One base star is not sufficient to assure victory over the Galactica.  Find her, but follow just beyond her scanner range.

**The Gun on Ice Planet Zero:**

> RIGEL Cylon base stars, quadrant Epsilon, closing rapidly.

**The Living Legend:**

> ADAMA Good Lord!  A Cylon base star?

Comment: Guess I missed the basestar references which can be easy to overlook. I went back and re watched parts of the original series and heard the basestar used along with baseship.

Answer (score 5):

This clip from the original series finale, "The Hand of God", confirms the use of the term "Base Star" at approx. 17-18 seconds in. There are additional uses of the term throughout the series, as noted in another answer using transcript excerpts.